Validate CSV with different delimiters in Laravel, fileinfo
Intro

I've got two files and I'm trying to post them to an endpoint via cURL.
file1.csv
header1,header2
row1_value1,row1_value2
row2_value1,row2_value2

file2.csv
header1;header2
row1_value1;row1_value2
row2_value1;row2_value2

Only file1.csv passes the validation rule mimes:csv.
curl -F "file=@file1.csv" -X POST http://host/api/endpoint 

I've tracked down the method that causes the validation to fail. It's in Symfony's FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser which in turn just does
(new \finfo(\FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, null))->file($path)


The question:

Is it possible to make finfo consider csv's delimited by a non-standard character, such as a semicolon ;, to be considered as a csv file so both of my example files pass Laravel's 'mimes:csv' validation?
I'm unfamiliar with how finfo works under the hood, but there is an optional $magic_database argument that can be passed in.

This might be an OS limitation. I created two duplicate csv files, one with a comma and one with a semi-colon. Using file --mime-type file.csv on the command line, the comma return application/csv, while the semicolon returned text/plain. This question says there isn't a mime-type for a semicolon separated file

You could probably create your own magic file to describe a CSV with semis and then pass that as an argument, but it seems rather unnecessary. It looks like the magic scanner only verifies that each row contains the same number of commas, which is hardly a worthwhile validation. You may as well just go by the filename extension. (Or do you not get the filename with this POST style of upload?)

You might need to skip the Laravel validation, and try to validate the file manually. One way to do it is make sure it can be properly parsed with fgetcsv and that you're getting expected data.

OK, you do get filename in $_FILES['file']['name'] here, so I think that's your only reasonable option. Otherwise you'd have to scan the whole file just to make a vague guess at the MIME type which doesn't actually provide any validation, and then your app is going to (hopefully?) explicitly validate the contents anyway. You could implement that as a Laravel validator and call it something like extension:csv or similar.

I feel like the least painful way to get what I want is to go the magic file route, since that's what Laravel ends up relying on when validating mimes (It uses a Symfony class that uses \finfo, which lets you to specify a magic file path). If anyone could point me in a good direction for this, I'd appreciate it.
